# Azure Cloudify Manager Web UI

Tags: user-interface, azure, cloudify

I have been trying to secure my Azure Cloudify Manager by putting on the Web UI where you need to log into the manager as shown here:

http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.4.0/manager_webui/login/

There doesnt seem to be any guides on it.

I am using version 3.4.0.2 that comes with the Installation of the Cloudify CLI

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Tom,

The article you point to says "After bootstrapping the manager with security support[...]" which means you would have had to use a manager (bootstrap) blueprint that had security enabled. I believe the doc resource you're looking for can be found here:

http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.4.0/manager/security/

For specific reference, you can find the manager blueprint and the corresponding "security" section outlined here:

https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-manager-blueprints/blob/3.4.0.2/types/manager-types.yaml#L82

Hope that helps.

- Joshua